# KVM Switch-Multiple Monitors-Rotating Displays

Tags: kvm-switch

I saw a similar post/question on this topic, but it was over ten years' old so I'm asking to see if modern tech may have caught up.  I've been researching KVM's, but I cannot quite find what I'm looking for (or don't understand the jargon now).

I'm looking to connect 2 monitors/computers thru a KVM to share one keyboard and mouse.  The catch is that I'd like to 'rotate' the view on my 'primary' monitor between computers.

In other words, on my secondary monitor, I would just display content from a laptop that I want to keep an eye on while I work on the primary.  When something queues on the secondary, I would want to manually switch the image/computer from the secondary to the primary and vice-versa without disconnecting cables, etc.

Is this available yet in a KVM?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, there are plenty of dual-monitor KVMs, but I've never seen one where one monitor gets set to a different input machine.

---

You can always use one basic kvm for each monitor though (keyboard and mouse on the main screen). Your computers need to support multiple displays, and the KVM should *not* support "fast switching" (where it keeps the disconnected PC's display active):

[image]

I've done this before (quite a while ago) with laptops, but it was kind of annoying when they'd decide the laptop screen was primary - though that may have gotten better over time. Personally, I recommend just using remote desktop or a similar tool if possible